# Recognition issue for window in different thread (tafx)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, automated-tests, tafx

We are trying to use Testing Automation FX for automating the basic workflow and testing in our application. The record function otherwise works flawlessly except in one specific case where the Windows Form in question is started from a different thread.

I noticed that the map generates an indistinguishable parent for the form in our application. The form is of type UIWindow and the following is the designer code for same.

```
            this.uiWindow2.Comment = null;
            this.uiWindow2.MatchedIndex = 0;
            this.uiWindow2.MsaaName = null;
            this.uiWindow2.MsaaRole = System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole.Client;
            this.uiWindow2.Name = "uiWindow2";
            this.uiWindow2.ObjectImage = ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(resources.GetObject("uiWindow2.ObjectImage")));
            this.uiWindow2.OwnedWindow = true;
            this.uiWindow2.Parent = this.Application;
            this.uiWindow2.UIObjectType = TestAutomationFX.UI.UIObjectTypes.Window;
            this.uiWindow2.UseCoordinatesOnClick = true;
            this.uiWindow2.WindowClass = "";
```

Since we don't have a parent window to our form, the only logical conclusion I could come up with was that windows was creating a wrapper around the form when it was started from a different thread.

**What this does is that when tafx runs the test cases, it sometimes fails to find uiWindow2 or hooks onto some other window thus failing the test. This is totally random. I would like to know if there is a possible solution for this situation?**

We are spawning window in a different thread using the following code snippet

```
    private void LaunchBlottFormNewOnNewThread()
    {
        Form blottForm = new BlottForm();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(blotterForm);
    }

    private void StartBlott()
    {
        Thread blottThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LaunchBlottFormNewOnNewThread));
        blottThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        blottThread.Name = "BlottThread";
        blottThread.IsBackground = true;
        blottThread.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe not what you want to hear but: a non-modal form in another thread? With caution it _may_ be even done but more often than not it's just wrong design, non-modal windows, background workers and dispatching are the way to go. In this case you start multiple main message loops (and repeat one-time initializations.) WHY? Note that message sent by Windows to your main message loop won't reach procs in your background threads (of course msgs to specific windows yes)....Isn't blotterForm.Show() enough? If you perform time-consuming operations you already needed a background worker...

Comment: Since this is a legacy product, this was done a long time ago and was essentially done because the UI in question keeps on receiving information in large amounts and at high rates, marshalling all that information to UI thread caused other UIs in the system to hang.

Comment: No need to dispatch _everything_, just calls to UI methods. That said caller do not usually need to use Control.Invoke() (blocking call), if you do not have a return value (or it can be decoupled from UI update logic) a simple Control.BeginInvoke() won't stop caller (the other UI) and your program will be _correct_. Playing with threads in UI is possible but incredibly tricky (and much harder in WinForms/GDI+ than in plain GDI)